# Getting all select2 instance in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to unbind keypress when select2 is focus, this seems to work

```
 $('#someId').on('select2-focus',function(){
    $(document).unbind('keypress');
});
```

but i want to get all select2 instance, i have tried

```
 $('.select2').on('select2-focus',function(){
    $(document).unbind('keypress');
});
```

but it is not working, i dont want to add ".custom_class" in each select2 i have in my page.
can someone help me on this one? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

In case anyone was still interested in the answer for the original question, i.e., „Getting all select2 instance in DOM“:

```
// The $element can be a narrower scope, or the entire document.
$element = $(document);
$element.find('select').each(function (i, select) {
    var $select = $(select);

    // Make sure that the select has Select2.
    if($select.hasClass("select2-hidden-accessible")) {
         // Perform your action, e.g.:
         $select.on('select2-focus',function(){
             $(document).unbind('keypress');
         });
         // You can also use the console for debugging:
         // console.log($select);
    }
});
```

The `$select.hasClass("select2-hidden-accessible")` check is taken from the original docs: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/methods#checking-if-the-plugin-is-initialized

But notice, that the 'select2-focus' event might not exist anymore, as it is not listed here: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events . You should be able to use 
`$select.find('.select2-selection__rendered').on('focus', function ...)`, but I did not test that.

For a working example of how this can be used, see my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bradacjan/pe3xL2sm/) for a [Select2 issue](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/4220). Notice the `function unobscurePlaceholdersOfSelect2()`.

Comment: Or shorter: `$('.select2-hidden-accessible').on('select2-focus', () => {$(document).unbind('keypress');});`

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('.select2-container').each(function(i,el){
    $(el).data('select2').close()
})
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't know what's your html.
but try it?
`jQuery( "[attribute='value']" )`

for example:
`$("input[type='text']")`